# AWS RDS no longer accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a RDS instance which is publicly accessible, i was able to connect to it a while ago but suddenly it has become inaccessible, getting error

`Error Code: 1045 Access denied for user 'root'@'IP' (using password: YES)`

Can't figure out a reason why it suddenly stopped working.

Comment: You were hacked and they changed the password?  Is there anything in the CloudWatch logs?

Comment: This error message suggests that you are successfully connecting to the database. However, the database is rejecting the login due to an incorrect username+password combination. An Amazon RDS database is normally accessed via a DNS Name (not an IP address), so it's a little strange that the error message is mentioning an IP address. Are you using the DNS Name to connect?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i haven't changed anything, neither the username nor the password and also didn't do anything with the security group or subnets setting, it was connecting moments ago but now i see this issue, cant seem to understand why thy could have happened suddenly.
I am using DB Endpoint i.e bac-s-qa-supply.c0*******.rds.amazonaws.com to connect

Answer (score 0):

Nilamber,
These are the things that you can do to debug the issue:

1. Check if RDS is accessible from the IP you're trying to connect.
2. Check if master username is correct (you can check from RDS console).
3. Check if master password is correct.
4. Change the master password from RDS console to see if it fix your issue.
5. Check if subnets in which RDS is provisioned are public.